# Ember - Get Value From Ember Data Array

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to loop over some objects in Ember in a controller, and return an array of their name attributes. I am however confused with what Ember is returning from the findAll function.

In a controller, I have the following function -

```
possibleGenres: function() {
    var genres = this.store.findAll('genre');
    var genreNames = genres.map(function(item, index, enumerable){
        return item.get('name');
    });
    return genreNames;
}.property(),
```

Logging genres.get('length') gives me 0.

I have proven that there are genres available in the findAll function, as when returning the returned genres from just the findAll function, they are displayed in the template.

Am I misunderstanding something crucial about Ember controllers here?

As ever, any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As others have stated, the problem is that `findAll` returns a promise, so you will have to use `.then()` to wait until the promise is resolved before the data is available to work with.

I think a cleaner way to approach this would be to set `genres` as a property and then have `genreNames` as a computed property that observes the `genres` array. Note, that Ember automatically unwraps promises when computed properties return them, so you don't have to use `.then()` in this situation:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  genreNames: Ember.computed.mapBy('genre', 'name'),

  genres: function() {
    return this.store.findAll('genre');
  }.property()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

```
this.store.all("genre") works better for you.
```

findAll will return a Promise, not the records you want.
if you try

```
genres.then(function(result){
    var genreNames = result.map(function(item, index, enumerable){
    return item.get('name');
});
```

you will have your results.

the problem is, that it's asynchronous. genreNames will be undefined, while you return it.
You could start a workaround with an observer, to solve this problem.

f.e.

```
possibleGenres: [],
possibleGenresDidChange: function(){
    //code...
    this.set("possibleGenres",result);        
}.obersves("possibleGenresTrigger"),
possibleGenresTrigger: false,
```

to update the property, switch the TriggerState between true and false. But it's a bit ugly. I do it some times the same way, because I found no better solution handling asynchronous requests in Controllers.

But, like written in the first line, perhaps store.all() works fine for you.

Comment: this.store.all("genre").get('length') or this.store.all("genre").toArray().length still returns 0, so I'm still getting the same...

Answer (score 0):

Since findAll was returning a promise, as pointed out by lukkysam, the correct solution would be to use `then` on the returned value like so.

```
possibleGenres: function() {
    var genreNames = [];
    this.store.findAll("genre").then(function(genres){
        genres.forEach(function(genre){
            genreNames.push(genre.get('combinedName'));
        });
    });
    return genreNames;
}.property(),
```

Comment: If you do that you'll return an empty array long before the promise has resolved.